# Query Devices on Azure IoT Hub STARTS_WITH MAC Address

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

I'm trying to filter the devices on my IoT Hub, I need to get only devices that starts with specific Mac Address.

This is the query I'm trying:

```
SELECT * FROM devices where starts_with(deviceId, 'D8B0')
```

But I'm getting

> Internal Server Error

I also tried:

```
SELECT * FROM devices where index_of(deviceId, 'D8B0') = 0
```

With same results

I tried from the Query Explorer on the Azure Portal, Postman and .Net SDK

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, what did you end up doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you cannot achieve what you're looking for using a query. As per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-query-language#functions), "when querying twins and jobs the only supported function is: `IS_DEFINED(property)`"

You can however use the `starts_with()` operator in your routing rule, so maybe that will do the trick for you. If not, you may want to add a specific tag to your device twins to indicate their 'type' as per your rule on MAC address prefix.

Comment: Oh, I missed that line.Great idea about the type, thanks a lot.

Comment: So assuming I have 10000s of devices how am I supposed to find/filter specific devices based on some condition/pattern like device id? Seems like a big oversight.